# Function for referencing values associated with specific factor values

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have a fairly large list looking something like this, where I have the first two variables stored are factors

```
Product Vendor   Sales    Product sales share
a       x          100    
b       y          200     
a       y          250     
c       y          700  
a       z          150
```

Ideally, I'd like to create a new column containing the vendors share of that product's total sales i.e. Share_{p=a,v=x} = 100/(100+250+150)

I figure lapply() would be viable but not sure how to write the function

```
> dput(list)
list(structure(list(Product = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), Vendor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(100, 
200, 250, 700, 150)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)))
```

Comment: Can use `dput()` to wrap the data? It is unclear what structure you have in input and what structure is in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` package, you could calculate the total sales for each product, then calculate the vendor share based on individual vendor and total sales.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(Total_Sales = sum(Sales),
         Vendor_Share = Sales/Total_Sales)
```

A base R approach could use `prop.table` as an alternative:

```
df$Vendor_Share <- with(df, ave(Sales, Product, FUN = prop.table))
```

**Output**

```
  Product Vendor Sales Vendor_Share
1       a      x   100          0.2
2       b      y   200          1.0
3       a      y   250          0.5
4       c      y   700          1.0
5       a      z   150          0.3
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Product = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), Vendor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(100, 
200, 250, 700, 150), Vendor_Share = c(0.2, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```